# как одной командой создать несколько файлов с датой в одной папке (linux)?

Tags: linux, unix

как одной командой создать несколько файлов с датой в одной папке (linux) ?

Comment: Напишите понятнее, что хотите сделать.

Comment: Задание : в 5 созданных файлов, которые находятся в одной папке , одним пайпом записать одинаковую дату

Comment: man date; man tee; учебные задания приветствуются только при попытках их самостоятельно решить...

Comment: Спасибо) задание не мое, попросили помочь чем смогу)

Answer (score 5):

1. «с датой» внутри:

   ```
   $ echo "2018/05/11" | tee путь/к/каталогу/{файл1,файл2}
   ```
2. пустые «с (указанной) датой» модификации:

   ```
   $ touch -d "2018/05/11" путь/к/каталогу/{файл1,файл2}
   ```